# Can I read mail using C++/CLI?

Tags: email, c++-cli, smtpclient

I can send mail using SmtpClient class, but are there any classes that allow reading mails? I tried to find something out, but it wasn't sucsessfull.

Comment: C++/CLI is not C++, much as JavaScript is not Java.  Should not have the `c++` tag, and it already has the correct `c++-cli` tag.

Comment: What do you mean by "reading mails"? An SMTP server? A POP3/IMAP client? Something that can display downloaded email messages on a screen?

Comment: No such class in the framework.  Even SmtpClient is no longer recommended by Microsoft, they suggest MailKit instead.  Which also supports reading mail.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe others can correct me but SmtpClient class is C# and not C++ right?

I don't know how up-to-date it is but here is [EmailArchitect's tutorial for "Retrieve Email and Parse Email in C++/CLI/CLR](https://www.emailarchitect.net/eagetmail/kb/managedc.aspx?cat=0). It looks like it uses EmailArchitect's binary so it's unfortunate but it could be a paid route.

Another way could be researching the libcurl/curl/cURL route which supports multiple protocols and have many examples online (though I haven't checked them out myself).